# Django with Apache and mod_wsgi getting a 403(Forbidden)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get a Django app running on Apache with mod_wsgi. I got a 403(Forbidden) for both any file in /static and /(the Django app). The apache user has permission to the wsgi.py and can list /apps/{DIR}/static. I even changed the user and group of all the file/directories in /apps/{DIR}. I can su to the apache user can traverse to wsgi.py. I can manually run apache is debug mode with httpd -X and everything works fine! (I can access the Django app and the static content) But when I run it normally it does not work, I get a 403.

RHEL 6.2, 
Python 2.6.6,
Django 1.3,
httpd-2.2.15,
mod_wsgi-3.2

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /apps/{DIR}/{APP_NAME}/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /apps/{DIR}/{APP_NAME}

<Directory /apps/{DIR}/{APP_NAME}/apache>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static /apps/{DIR}/static
<Directory /apps/{DIR}/static>
  Order allow,deny
  Options Indexes
  Allow from all
  IndexOptions FancyIndexing

  #Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

error in httpd/error_log

```
[...] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[...] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: Can't open directory for index: /apps/{DIR}/static/
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I have very stange problem with CentOS. Forbidden appears when is start httpd using `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd` start and doesn't when I do `sudo /usr/sbin/httpd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running with SELinux enabled?

Are all directories from '/' down to the static media directory readable to Apache user, not just the directory itself?

Comment: Yes, SELinux was running. I fixed SELinux and it is working just fine now.

Thanks